# Howto get the sum of a column, grouped by month, where the date column is a relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have a problem I can't figure out. Fyi, I'm using Laravel 5.6

I have an `offers` table and a `requests` table;

```
offers-table
- id
- quotation_amount
- ...

requests-table
- id
- offer_id
- date
- ...
```

This is a One to Many relationship. To clarify: An offer can be requested multiple times and a request belongs to only one offer. (Relationships are setup correctly.)

Now I need to know the *total sum* of the `quotation_amount` *per month*. The *first request* (selected by the date column) *is leading* in determining the month to be grouped in. The other requests should be ignored basically.

The reason we need this is so we can see how much we in sold compared to what we offered to clients. If we offer for 1.000.000 on products in a month, but we sell for only 100.000 (10%) in that same month, there is something wrong on the sales department or our offers are to expensive :).

So to get the data to compare with I have a `projects`-table which has a `contract_sum` and `sale_date` column. That was a lot easier because I just could do this;

```
$sales['projects'] = array_replace(
    array_fill_keys(range(1, 12), 0), $projects->groupBy('sale_date.month')->map(function($projects) { 
        return $projects->pluck('contract_sum')->sum(); 
    })->toArray()
);
```

Output from code above;

```
Array
(
    [1] => 760335
    [2] => 1154054
    [3] => 683762
    //... untill 12
)
```

But to get the same output for the offer quotation amount I need the date to come from a relationship, which can have more than one result, I don't know how to do it. I also tried something like the following and different variations on it;

```
$offers = Offer::with(['requests' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('date')->take(1);
}])->whereHas('requests', function($query) {
    $query->whereMonth('date', $month);
})->get();
```

But above doesn't work, because if there are two requests in two different months for only one offer, it would be counted in both months.

Who can help me or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using raw query :

```
SELECT MONTH(r.first_date) AS offer_month, SUM(o.quotation_amount) as total
FROM offers o INNER JOIN 
(
 SELECT offer_id, MIN(date) first_date FROM requests r
 GROUP BY offer_id
) r 
ON o.id=r.offer_id
WHERE YEAR(r.first_date)=...
GROUP BY offer_month
```

Comment: Its working! I only should check the results on correctness. Can you explain the `first_date` part? Where is this coming from?

Comment: this sentence : "The first request (selected by the date column) is leading in determining the month to be grouped in. The other requests should be ignored basically." is equal to "select the minimum date for each offer_id".

Comment: I think I understand the  idea. First_date in Month(r.first_date) referreces to first_date (which is the outcome of min(date) in the inner join part

Comment: Its returning the expected result!